# remove ocx fully

Tags: delphi

When I try to remove the registered ocx(activex) in 'Import ActiveX Control',
But the ocx still displays in Delphi IDE Tab'ActiveX'

Is it possible to remove ocx fully?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find which package the OCX was installed into, remove it from that package, and then re-install that package.